# "metadata-generation-failed" due to "FileNotFound error during installation of scrappy

Tags: python, pip, filenotfoundexception, setup.py

I am trying to install the Python module Scrappy but the requirements.txt file is not found. I'm using Python 3.10.4 and pip 22.2.2. I tried running

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

which produced the same error

I typed this command into Windows Powershell:

```
pip install scrappy
```

Standard output:

```
Collecting scrappy
  Using cached Scrappy-0.3.0.alpha.4.tar.gz (17 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting guessit
  Using cached guessit-3.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (167 kB)
Collecting tvdb_api
  Using cached tvdb_api-3.1.0.tar.gz (23 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting scrappy
  Using cached Scrappy-0.3.0.alpha.3.tar.gz (16 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Using cached Scrappy-0.3.0.alpha.2.tar.gz (16 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Using cached Scrappy-0.3.0.alpha.tar.gz (16 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Using cached Scrappy-0.2.10.beta.14.tar.gz (16 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Using cached Scrappy-0.2.10.beta.13.tar.gz (15 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Using cached Scrappy-0.2.10.beta.12.tar.gz (15 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Using cached Scrappy-0.2.10.beta.11.tar.gz (15 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
```

Standard error:

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\mohm7\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-au7_wkmw\scrappy_e1f30a064214471db41bbe20fedce6c6\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
          with open('requirements.txt') as f:
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: If you are looking for the web crawler its called `scrapy` or there is `PyScrappy` .  -   `scrappy` is a tool that changes the name of video files, and doesn't have a requirements.txt in the public github repo

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
pip install --ignore-installed scrappy
```

or, if you have scrappy listed in requirements.txt (make sure you specify version of scrappy), assuming requirements.txt is in your current directory

```
pip install --ignore-installed -r requirements.txt
```